# flask app builder user should see only own content

Tags: python, flask, flask-appbuilder

Hi i want that the user is only seeing it's own content which was created by themself. In flask i created a user table and every other table as a reference to the table. So when the view is called i filter for the current user and only show the entries for the user. I now checked out flask app builder and it has some nice user management but it seems that it has nothing like i need.

My solution would be: Create a reference from my table to the user table and do it like i did it with plain flask. I am just wondering if there is a better way to do this and maybe there is allready something in appbuilder what i have to activate but don't see yet.

my flask solution:

this is what i add to the model

```
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

this is how i query it in the routes

```
articles_pos = ArticlePos.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A solution can be found in the examples of fab itself. see https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/tree/master/examples/extendsecurity

in my particular case i made the following changes

in the model i adde the follwoing:

```
class MyUser(User):
    __tablename__ = "ab_user"
```

and in the class where i reference the user table

```
user = relationship("MyUser")

user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('ab_user.id'), default=get_user_id, nullable=False)
```

you still need the the function:

```
@classmethod
    def get_user_id(cls):
        try:
            return g.user.id
        except Exception:
            return None
```